# Do I inform my Professor that our digital exam isn't recording us?

Tags: ethics, exams

For one of the classes I am taking at University, our exams are administered online. We were told that each of these exams would start a special browser that recorded you as you took the test, and also prevented you from visiting other tabs in the browser.

A few minutes before our first test, one of the other students in the class tells me that his friend from the earlier section took it and it didn't record him. I didn't run the risk, but I am quite certain that the browser is not recording us when we take these exams. The light for my laptop camera does not go on, and in past experiences with online exams we were told to download a special browser (you can take the exams for this class on chrome, firefox, etc.)

I'm torn, and I'm a little annoyed considering I got a 77% on the first exam. Ultimately, I don't think I will tell the professor, that really isn't my nature. However, in a situation like this I felt I should at least turn to strangers on the internet to possibly change my mind.

Should I tell or not?

(the exams are not curved)

Comment: It certainly couldn't hurt to inform the instructor or, even just ask. Is there a particular reason why you do or do not think you should? As in, you're afraid they'll assume you're guilty of having tried to cheat?

Comment: @tonysdg my concern is that we will have to take the exam again, and I feel that I would rather deal with a few students cheating than possibly create a problem for myself through trying to do the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

From your comment, I note your concern that if you report the matter, you might be required to sit the exam again.  I think that is unlikely.  It is unlikely that your professor would impose additional work on the students due to a technical error that was not their fault.  It is more likely that your professor would be glad to have been informed of the technical problems, and would use this information to try to have the technology run correctly in future exams.  It's really up to you, but as an academic with experience in teaching, it is certainly useful if students report problems, so that you can improve future iterations of your teaching.

Comment: Upvoted, exactly what I hope for from my students in terms of information. I like and want the feedback to improve the system, BUT don't look to replace an exam for such a small issue. Corrections are necessary but usually small and limited to one question...